# Defining XML file without its Schema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I believed that we create XML's `Schema`s to define the XML elements and its structure. I thought, we must define the `XSD` before we create a `XML` file. In other word, `xml` file without its `xsd` is meaningless.

Today I run this code,

```
   XmlWriter XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("Test.xml");

            XmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();

            XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Users");
            XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("User");
            XmlWriter.WriteStartAttribute("Salman", "24");

            XmlWriter.WriteString("Salman");

            XmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            XmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
            XmlWriter.Close();
```

When I find my output, there was not any `XSD` file. Only `Test.xml`.
So my question is:

What is the exact role of `XSD` files?

If I were right, why doesn't the C# generate the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSDs are used for validation of XML files, but are optional and not required. If you are writing / reading from the same application, and you control all access to the XML file with error/exception handling for when things don't work, you don't need the XSD.

When passing data between applications, the XSD serves as the contract that ensures both parties understand and agree on the format of the XML file being passed.